# jssor slideshow works in ie but chrome has problems

Tags: slider, jssor

I have a jssor slider up,  but the pictures don't show up on second section in Chrome unless I put it in incognito mode, but work fine in IE / opera.

Any suggestions

http://www.webstitcher.com/works.html

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this problem, it appears that an update to Chrome has broken href tags while using Jssor.  I was able to get them working again by adding a style of display:block to the href.  If you do not like this method I believe by downloading the newest version of Jssor and replacing the files will fix the problem, even if its the same version.

```
  <div>
      <a u="image" href="www.example.com" style="display:block">
          <img src="/example.png" />
      </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: I actually did update + I tried your fix, still not fixed 

strange thing is it works in incognito mode

Answer (score 0):

The style for u="image" solved the image display problem...

However, there is still a problem with the captions...

Here is the Shop with the problem https://www.sound-spirit.de/shop/

FireFox ist OK still....

Comment: The solution ist to set the "$HWA"-parameter to "false".

After that it works again.